# Infinite number of Derivatives

Tags: derivatives

Is there a kind of function (other than trigonometric) that you can take infinite amount of derivatives without it ever becoming 0. Algebraic functions now matter how long, or how many powers  it has it can eventually be derived to 0. I am not including trigonometric functions because they are circular in nature. I mean a function that will not go on a circle like trigonometric do; But will have infinite derivatives.

Comment: Exponentials, though these are closely related to trig functions. Another example is any hypergeometric function $_pF_q$ with $q \ge p$.

Comment: The $n$-th derivative of a function $f$  is identically $0$ for some $n$ if and only if $f$ is a polynomial function.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Surely not any hypergeometric function... ${}_pF_q(-n,a_1,\dotsc;b_1,\dotsc;z)$ is a polynomial, after all!

Comment: @Chappers Oh true! I didn't think about that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Certainly, $f(x) = Ce^{\pm x} \neq 0$ for a fixed non-zero $C$.

Answer (score 21):

$\log{x}$ and its various derivatives and antiderivatives.

Really, polynomials are the exception here: it is easy enough to prove by induction that any smooth function $f$ for which $d^nf/dx^n=0$ is a polynomial of degree less than $n$.

Comment: And it's a bit less easy to prove that any function which is infinitely differentiable and has some derivative equal to zero at each point is still a polynomial. See [the MathOverflow question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/34059/if-f-is-infinitely-differentiable-then-f-coincides-with-a-polynomial)

Comment: @MarkS. a lot of the posters here add the words 'smooth' or 'infinitely differentiable', but it unnecessarily complicates it -- if the $n$'th derivative of $f$ for some $n$ is $0$, then it trivially implies that $f$ is smooth and there is no need to add this condition. If the $n$'th derivative of $f$ is $0$ for some $n$, then $f$ is a polynomial function.

Answer (score 17):

The only smooth functions for which a derivative of some order is identically zero are polynomials.

This is essentially just computing $\int^{(n)}0\;dx$ for arbitrary $n$ (don't forget the additive constant at each stage).

Comment: The condition 'smooth' is redundant, since $(0)^{(n)}=0$ for any $n$.

Comment: @user31415: The function is smooth *a priori* as OP speaks of taking derivatives of arbitrary order everywhere. I should point out that I have implicitly assumed that the domain is all of $\mathbb R$ (or at least connected) since the result does not follow otherwise: consider the function $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb R$ with $x\mapsto |x|$; its second derivative vanishes identically on its domain, but it isn't a polynomial (in fact, it is smooth as well).

Answer (score 7):

In addition to what everyone else is saying: rational functions that aren't polynomials, such as $\dfrac1x$, $\dfrac1{1-x}$, $\dfrac x{x^2+2x+2}$, etc.

Also things like $x^x$, which is halfway between a power (e.g. $x^n$) and an exponential (e.g. $n^x$). It grows faster than exponentials, by the way. You might not have learned how to differentiate this, yet.

Honestly, anything other than polynomials.

Comment: How is $x^x$ halfway between $n^x$ and $x^n$. It was my understanding that it is asymptotically greater than both... Am I missing something here?

Comment: @k_g as I understand columbus, is _conceptually_ somewhere in between, as it has both exponentiation and a power.

Comment: @k_g: Note that expressions like $x^x$ are easy to differentiate if you know the generalized power rule $$\left(f^g\right)' =gf^{g-1}\cdot f'+ f^g\log f\cdot g'$$ So it really is "halfway in between" powers and exponentials. This generalizes both. If either $f$ or $g$ is constant, you recover the corresponding classical rule because the corresponding derivative vanishes.

Comment: One way to differentiate $x^x$ is to rewrite it as $e^{x\ln x}$ and use the Chain and Product rules.

Comment: To differentiate $x^x$ you can just use the two rules $(x^a)'=ax^{a-1}$ and $(a^x)'=a^x\log a$, they dont quite work on their own, but if you just sum them together it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Further to other answers here, only polynomials of positive integer order eventually run to a zero derivative.  The repeated derivative of any polynomial $x^{y}$ where $y$ is non-integer or where $y<0$ will never become zero.  (The logarithm is a special starting point for the latter case.)

Answer (score 2):

Let's suppose a function $f$ is given by a power series which converges within a open set $D$ (for simplicity, let's assume $0 \in D$).  Then, we can write

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$$

provided that infinitely many $a_n$'s are nonzero, $f^{(k)}(0) = k!a_k$ will be nonzero for infinitely many $k$.  For example, $f(x)=e^x$ can be written as
$$e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}x^n$$
and the derivatives of $e^x$ never vanish.

Answer (score 1):

Of course there are, a simple example is $f(x)=e^x$. Since $\frac{d}{dx}e^x=e^x$, the $n$th derivative of $f(x)$ will also be $f(x)$, which will never be 0.

Comment: I should have included that one, I figured this one out too.

Comment: On the other hand, that particular example is technically circular in the same manner as the trig functions, just with a repetition interval of one.

Answer (score 0):

Many special functions, such as $\text{erf} (x),\Gamma(x), J_0 (x)$ etc have derivatives such that it will never equal 0 after $n$ derivatives.